# Using Vaadin components in a kotlin js project

Tags: vaadin, kotlin-js

This question is about a Kotlin JS project which uses the Kotlin Frontend Plugin.

I want to use some UI components from the [Vaadin Components library](https://vaadin.com/components).

I have two questions about this:

(1) What would be the best way to include web components in Kotlin JS

=> for my complete code, see the link to the source below. In summary the relevant details are:

**build.gradle.kts**

```
kotlinFrontend {
    npm {
        dependency("@vaadin/vaadin-grid")
    }
}
```

**vaadin.grid.Imports.kt**

```
@file:JsModule("@vaadin/vaadin-grid")
@file:JsNonModule
package vaadin.grid
external class GridElement {
    companion object
}
```

Why the `companion object`? I need it for the workaround (see below).

**foo.kt**

```
fun main() {

    document.getElementById("container")!!.append {
        vaadin_grid {
            attributes["id"] = "grid"
        }
    }

    initUI()

}

fun initUI() {
    // Force the side-effects of the vaadin modules. Is there a better way?
    console.log(GridElement)

    val grid = document.querySelector("#grid") /* ?? as GridElement ?? */
}
```

The `console.log` is the ugly workaround trick I want to avoid. If I don't *do anything* with GridElement then it's just not included in my bundle.

The `vaadin_grid` DSL is defined as a custom kotlinx.html tag which is unrelated code.

(2) I want to keep my code as typed as possible to avoid `asDynamic` but when I cast the `HTMLElement` to a Vaadin Element I get ClassCastExceptions (because `GridElement` is `undefined`).

For example I want to write something like this:

```
val grid : GridElement = document.querySelector("#grid") as GridElement
grid.items = ... // vs grid.asDynamic().items which does work
```

Here is how I define the external GridElement

**vaadin/button/Imports.kt**

```
@file:JsModule("@vaadin/vaadin-grid")
@file:JsNonModule

package vaadin.grid

import org.w3c.dom.HTMLElement

abstract external class GridElement : HTMLElement {
    var items: Array<*> = definedExternally
}
```

**build/node_modules/@vaadin/vaadin-grid/src/vaadin-grid.js**

```
...
customElements.define(GridElement.is, GridElement);
export { GridElement };
```

[Source example](https://github.com/dvekeman/kotlin-frontend-examples/tree/c5eaf9d08b8280f4663018824745b85b4cb5884a/05-kt-frontend-vaadin)

To run:

From the root of the git repo:

```
./gradlew 05-kt-frontend-vaadin:build && open 05-kt-frontend-vaadin/frontend.html
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer(s)

For the first question

> (1) What would be the best way to include web components in Kotlin JS

Instead of the `console.log` to trigger the side effects I use `require(...)`

```
external fun require(module: String): dynamic

fun main() {

    require("@vaadin/vaadin-button")
    require("@vaadin/vaadin-text-field")
    require("@vaadin/vaadin-grid")
    ...
}
```

(credits to someone's answer on the [kotlin-frontend-plugin list](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-frontend-plugin/issues/149))

> (2) I want to keep my code as typed as possible to avoid asDynamic

Instead of importing `@vaadin/vaadin-grid` I have to import the file which actually exposes the element. Then it seems to work and I can even add generics to my GridElement:

```
@file:JsModule("@vaadin/vaadin-grid/src/vaadin-grid")
@file:JsNonModule

package vaadin.grid

import org.w3c.dom.HTMLElement

abstract external class GridElement<T> : HTMLElement {
    var items: Array<out T> = definedExternally
}
```

This way I was able to get rid of all the `asDynamic`s

```
    val firstNameField = document.querySelector("#firstName") as TextFieldElement?
    val lastNameField = document.querySelector("#lastName") as TextFieldElement?
    val addButton = document.querySelector("#addButton") as ButtonElement?
    val grid = document.querySelector("#grid") as GridElement<Person>?

    val initialPeople: Array<out Person> = emptyArray()
    grid?.items = initialPeople

    addButton?.addEventListener("click", {
        // Read the new person's data
        val person = Person(firstNameField?.value, lastNameField?.value)

        // Add it to the items
        if(grid != null){
            val people = grid.items
            grid.items = people.plus(person)
        }

        // Reset the form fields
        firstNameField?.value = ""
        lastNameField?.value = ""
    })
```